# Chrome freeze on 2 of my 3 monitors, What can I do?

Tags: updates, 17.10, multiple-monitors, google-chrome

Ubuntu 17.10
Chrome: Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)

After an update the last week Chrome freeze on 2 of my 3 monitors, an important thing, those 2 monitors are connected on a different GPU, Firefox run perfect but I prefer chrome for development purposes.

Anyone knows what to do? or how to reverse that update? If needed.

Comment: This keeps happening, maybe submit a bug to the chrome repo?